# What's the benefit of conduit's leftovers?

Tags: haskell, conduit, haskell-pipes

I'm trying to understand the differences between *conduit* and *pipes*. Unlike *pipes*, *conduit* has the concept of leftovers. What are leftovers useful for? I'd like to see some examples where leftovers are essential.

And since *pipes* don't have the concept of leftovers, is there any way to achieve a similar behavior with them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Gabriella's point that leftovers are always part of parsing is interesting. I'm not sure I would agree, but that may just depend on the definition of parsing.

There are a large category of use cases which require leftovers. Parsing is certainly one: any time a parse requires some kind of lookahead, you'll need leftovers. One example of this is in the markdown package's [getIndented](https://github.com/snoyberg/markdown/blob/master/Text/Markdown/Block.hs#L300) function, which isolates all of the upcoming lines with a certain indentation level, leaving the rest of the lines to be processed later.

But a much more mundane set of examples lives in conduit itself. Any time you're dealing with packed data (like ByteString or Text), you'll need to read a chunk, analyze it somehow, use leftover to push back the extra, and then do something with the original content. Perhaps the simplest example of this is [dropWhile](https://github.com/snoyberg/conduit/blob/master/conduit/Data/Conduit/Binary.hs#L236).

In fact, I consider leftover to be such a core, basic feature of a streaming library that the new 1.0 interface for conduit doesn't even expose the option to users of disabling leftovers. I know of very few real-world use cases that don't need it in one way or another.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'm quite convinced now. Meanwhile, I was thinking about how to implement leftovers on top of a conduit-like library that doesn't have them natively. The idea is that a conduit with leftovers can be represented as a conduit returning `(Maybe i, r)`. My attempt (for conduit) is [here](https://gist.github.com/ppetr/5110909).

Comment: I think you have the right intuition, your implementation is very similar to how things work internally. I think you discovered the double-leftover issue, which is why leftovers are allowed to be stacked as multiple Leftover constructors in conduit.

Comment: Yet [another attempt](https://gist.github.com/ppetr/5110909#file-feedback-hs) (which I'll most likely use in my Scala library) for leftovers is to view leftovers as a kind of feedback: For `Pipe Void i (Either i o) u m r` we send any `Left i` back to its input using a an internal method that converts such a pipe into a standard one.

Comment: Could you please point to a simple example of a leftover? I looked at your dropWhile link, but it 404s. In the dropWhile case, what is the leftover?If possible, could you please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/44402598/409976? Thanks!

Comment: Hit spacebar to proceed through the slides from here: http://www.snoyman.com/reveal/conduit-yesod#/13/1. It's also covered in the Conduit tutorial, which I'd recommend reading: https://haskell-lang.org/library/conduit.

Answer (score 15):

I'll answer for `pipes`.  The short answer to your question is that the upcoming `pipes-parse` library will have support for leftovers as part of a more general parsing framework.  I find that almost every case where people want leftovers they actually want a parser, which is why I frame the leftovers problem as a subset of parsing.  You can find the current draft of the library [here](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Pipes-Parse-Library).

However, if you want to understand how `pipes-parse` gets it to work, the simplest possible way to implement leftovers is to just use `StateP` to store the pushback buffer.  This requires only defining the following two functions:

```
import Control.Proxy
import Control.Proxy.Trans.State

draw :: (Monad m, Proxy p) => StateP [a] p () a b' b m a
draw = do
    s <- get
    case s of
        []   -> request ()
        a:as -> do
            put as
            return a

unDraw :: (Monad m, Proxy p) => a -> StateP [a] p () a b' b m ()
unDraw a = do
    as <- get
    put (a:as)
```

`draw` first consults the pushback buffer to see if there are any stored elements, popping one element off the stack if available.  If the buffer is empty, it instead requests a new element from upstream.  Of course, there's no point having a buffer if we can't push anything back, so we also define `unDraw` to push an element onto the stack to save for later.

Edit: Oops, I forgot to include a useful example of when leftovers are useful.  Like Michael says, `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` are useful cases of leftovers.  Here's the `drawWhile` function (analogous to what Michael calls `takeWhile`):

```
drawWhile :: (Monad m, Proxy p) => (a -> Bool) -> StateP [a] p () a b' b m [a]
drawWhile pred = go
  where
    go = do
        a <- draw
        if pred a
        then do
            as <- go
            return (a:as)
        else do
            unDraw a
            return []
```

Now imagine that your producer was:

```
producer () = do
    respond 1
    respond 3
    respond 4
    respond 6
```

... and you hooked that up to a consumer that used:

```
consumer () = do
    evens <- drawWhile odd
    odds  <- drawWhile even
```

If the first `drawWhile odd` didn't push back the final element it drew, then you would drop the `4`, which wouldn't get correctly passed onto to the second `drawWhile even` statement`.