# conduit: read-only source possible?

Tags: haskell, conduit

Suppose that I have a source `keypads :: Producer IO Keypad` that produces a stream of sensitive data such as one-time keypads.

Now if my library exposes `keypads`, an end-user might connect `keypads` to two sinks, let's call them `good` and `bad`, where `bad` requests a value and reads it, but then returns it back upstream via `leftover`. Later on, the `good` sink might consume the same keypad previously read by `bad`. The enduser might be oblivious to this happening, for example if `good` and `bad` are provided by external libraries.

**Is there any way to design a read-only source in conduit that discards leftover data?**

(I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15263700/1973301) that it's not possible to disable reusing leftovers, but as I'm new to conduits, maybe there's a different way to design the architecture that I'm not seeing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two options:

1. Wrap `bad` with a `map id Conduit` which will prevent leftovers from propagating. I'm thinking your code would look something like:

   ```
   keypads $$ (CL.map id =$= bad) >> good
   ```
2. Drop down to the `Pipe` layer of abstraction and call `injectLeftovers` on `bad` to ensure that all leftovers are consumed there and then discarded.

I'm guessing (1) is the approach you'll want.